# Issue with VS 2010 check accessibility feature

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, accessibility

I am working on the accessibility issues in my project. I am using VS 2010 added a .htm file to the project and pasted the following html.

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4qie.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="">Submit Go Question</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When i right click on the html page in visual studio and say check accessibility it throws the following error.

> Error 18  **WCAG 13.1** : Clearly identify the target of links.  Do not
>   use "Click Here".  Use something descriptive, like "Map of
>   campus."  C:\Raghu\Official\MVC\Lab 01 -ASP.NET-MVC-Fundamentals
>   MVC3\Source\Ex01-CreatingMusicStoreProject\Begin\TestAccessibility\TestAccessibility\TestPage.htm 8

When i analysed this error i found that whenever there is a word inside the HTML anchor tag with the combination of letters **"Go"** it throws this error.

The error is not thrown for **GO** or **go** letter combinations. The error is thrown even for words like **Goals**, **Governance** etc.,

I think this has got something to do with the combination of "G" in capital followed by "o" in lower case.

How to resolve that error (escaping the combination "Go")?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an error as such, but more a guideline for the text you should have as your link.

this page http://www.w3.org/WAI/wcag-curric/sam97-0.htm should give you an idea of what you should have as your links.

in your example you have `<a href="">Submit Go Question</a>`, the link text doesn't make sense. By using the word Submit, you are implying that the link is a button for accessibility purposes, when it actually is a link that will not submit a form.

better ways to put your text that might meet accessibility guidelines are

```
<a href="" title="Begin the questionnaire">Start the questionnaire</a>
<a href="" title="Go to question 5">Next question</a>
<a href="" title="Go to question 3">Previous question</a>
```

basically you have to describe where the links are taking you. going of the W3 guidelines, `click here` is a bad example, as accessibility-wise you might say 'click where?'

Comment: Hi Kolin, Thanks for your update! I had put in dummy text for example.However the actual markup goes like this! <a href="">Goals & Objectives</a> This happens when the anchor text has "Go". Another example can be "Governance". Appreciate your response!

Comment: if you enter the title attribute in the link tag as `title="View goals and objectives"` does that help, also, do you still get the issue if you use `view goals &amp; objectives` as the link text?

Comment: Hi Kolin! I am not allowed to change the case of the word from "Goals & Objectives" to "goals & objectives". Can you please help!

Comment: I have tried the options you have given above. But without changing the case for the words "Goals & Objectives" it doesn't work.

Comment: Automated accessibility checkers can only go so far. Read the WCAG 2 guidelines, think about how a screen reader user (who may encounter that link out of context - screen readers allow the scanning of all links on a page) will hear it and use your best judgement.

Comment: don't use the title attribute, not everybody has access to it

Comment: @RyanB thanks for pointing that out, just done a bit of research and reading here http://www.rnib.org.uk/professionals/webaccessibility/wacblog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?id=38 , never realised that the title tag caused problems for accessibility, thanks